# Windows 10 on ASUSTec doesn't recognize private network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I moved to new place and can't connect to private network. Windows doesn't even see the network as available, although it easy recognize on my work laptop and cell phone, which tells me it is not the network, but windows issue. so far I reinstalled windows, but it didn't fix the problem and I'm not sure what else needs to be done. I turned off firewall for private networks, but it didn't help.
Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the network is on 5 GHz band (only) and your work laptop and cell phone have 5 GHz radios, while your other computer does not, evidently.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding! Is it something that can be adjust/fixed? If so -- would you be kind to tell me how?

Comment: Adjusted - no. You could buy a USB WiFi adapter in the 5 GHz band as a crude fix. In most cases you cannot upgrade the internal radio, or it's not remotely cost-effective to do so, anyway. You might check what channels your other devices are connecting to as a means of verifying my diagnosis. The particular model number of your Asus device would also help to verify what WLAN radio it shipped with.

Comment: Does Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced N6235 tell you anything? Where can I find info that it has not WLAN, but WoWLAN... and that adapter set up for auto for 2.4 and 5.2 band?